# How to change data base schema

Tags: sqlite

I am using sqlite older version for developing my application.

For some problem i have altered one of the table for adding new column. Previously this table data is stored in integers, after altering the table they have changed to strings.  How can I get the altered string data again to integers, while querying how to query these fields?

Answer (score 17):

SQLite only allows [very limited changes to be done to an existing table](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html). For anything else, you should:

1. **rename** the old table,
2. **make a new table** with the old name and with the correct column definitions,
3. **copy the data** over, and
4. **drop** the old table.

Do this within a single transaction, of course!
Also, practice on another database before trying this with your production data.

Answer (score 0):

Connect to your SQL lite database from visual studio server explorer and make schema changes from there. There is a edit schema option when you right click on the table you want to make changes.